# Matlab function deployment in RaspberryPi for HIL simulation

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, real-time, simulink, matlab-engine

We have been working with a real time simulator and tried to implement an optimization algorithm using simulink but it appears that will not work since the C code generation is not possible with optimvar functions. Therefore, we tried to use the simulink compiler SDK to generate a python package and we run it in a python environment (the same comupter) and the results seem to work.

The issue found here is how to implement the package generated by the compiler SDK in a Raspberry environement and establish the communication with the real time simulator.

Does anyone had the same issue or does anyone worked with this before?

we followed the instruction in this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html?searchHighlight=matlab%20to%20python&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_matlab%20to%20python

Comment: The page on your link states that the compiled Python package needs MATLAB Runtime, which isn't available for the Raspberry Pi. If you need your optimisation code to run standalone on the Raspberry Pi I guess you'll need to reimplement the optimisation algorithm yourself using only functions that are [supported by MATLAB Coder on the Pi](https://uk.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-matlab.html).